# How to insert an object with multiple sub object with autogenerated key in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to insert a set of object with multiple sub object as shown in image

[image has snipped structure of firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26a3s.png)

i have a class Item in which i have ItemName and second class Price in which i have Cost

Currently iam adding ItemName first using 
ref.child("Items").push.setvalue(Item)

then using that push key iam adding the prices

i want to add both item and price at the same time how can i do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a `Price` object in your `Items` class. The code should look like this:

```
class Price {
    private String cost;
    //other fields

    Price() {}

   //public setters and getters for all fields
}
```

and the second model class

```
class Items {
    private String itemName;
    private Price price;
    //other fields

    Item(){}

   //public setters and getters for all fields
}
```

Then, when you create the object of the `Items` class use this code:

```
 Items items = new Items();
 items.setItemName("Spring");
 Price price = new Price();
 price.setCost("10.00");
 items.setPrice(price);
 yourRef.setValue(items);
```

In this way you can set your data at once.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Alex Mamo:    for each item i want to add multiple prices with unique key as i have shown in image.. if i add second price it will update the old price if i use your logic..

Comment: In this case you need to set the name and the costs separately because are located in different locations and you need to use the push() method once for items and once for the costs.